# How to make this texture look round and smooth?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, texture-painting, shader-nodes

I want to remove the hard edge of this texture as its bend and turn it into more of a round edge as show in this reference image

[image: Reference Image]

But with the existing geometry, I can only get hard edges. I cannot figure out the way to do this.

[image]

[image: Geometry]

Comment: hello, with a high-poly mesh you won't be able to create a smooth edge, you should better create a low-poly first, it will be much easier to work and modify, then when you're glad you apply the Subdivision Surface modifier if necessary (but always keep a low-poly version with the modifier unapplied)

Comment: Especially if the orange section is not just colouring, but a separate panel.. in which case it would be a separate, discontinuous mesh?

Comment: Thanks for these suggestion the low-poly approach worked out for me.